# Bash error: "line 8: [: 2: unary operator expected"

Tags: bash, shell

Please help me with this error I received with a shell script in Bash:
`line 8: [: 2: unary operator expected`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input your number for factorial calculation: "
read $nr

counter=2
factorial=1

while [ $counter -le $nr ]
do
 factorial=$(( $factorial * $counter ))
 counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done

echo "The result " $nr "! is:"
echo $factorial
```

Something is wrong with the while line. Maybe the `$nr` is not used correctly?

Comment: use `while [[ ... ]]`

Comment: In the future, please paste the code directly into the question, don't link to an image.

Comment: BTW, consider `while (( counter <= nr )); do`

Comment: @SMA, negative -- if you're going to use a bash extension for math, use the one that *actually creates a math context* and lets you use C-style operators; anything else is silly.

Comment: BTW, I didn't actually vote to close off-topic, I closed as two broad: There are two different problems, correctly using `read` and correctly using the test operator for math, being conflated. (Validating assumptions, ie. by `echo "$nr"` after the `read` before anything else, might have helped that be tracked down).

Comment: sorry for this. I tried to paste the code, but was a long line and hard to understand...Seems someone helped me and edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` takes *name* of the variable, not its value. You need to replace `read $nr` with `read nr`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be having trouble formatting your question, so I cannot see it, but generally you get that error if you have something like `if [ $a -ne $b ]` but one of `$a` or `$b` is empty, so basically the interpreter sees something like `if [ -ne $b ]`. They ways to avoid it are either

1. Ensure that the variables are set before such a test, or
2. Quote the variables, so even an empty or undefined one will be seen as an empty string. Although at this point you can only use string, not numerical comparison. `if [ "$a" != "$b" ]`